# Cake php root directory file access

Tags: cakephp, xml-sitemap

Hello community I want to Create custom sitemap in root/public_html directory and i want to view as raalic.us/sitemap.xml
So how can i access root directory any file or specific file in cake php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have set the cakephp based web app to **root/public_html**
- CakePHP has its own root directory and it is called **webroot**
- .htaccess redirects all http requests to that directory
- it contains publicly available files (css, js, img, ..)
- you can put your sitemap.xml in it

so the correct path to the xml file is: `root/public_html/webroot/sitemap.xml`